# Login authenticates user with any password

Tags: authentication, passport.js, mean-stack, bcrypt, passport-local

I have a simple login form that I created. It seems to authenticate any existing user as long as the password field has something in it. Obviously, it is a huge security flaw. I'm new to mean stack and using passport to authenticate users seemed easy but not sure if I did it wrong.

This is my backend code using passportjs:

app.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
require('./config/passport');
app.use(passport.initialize());
```

routes/index.js

```
const ctrlAuth = require('../controllers/authentication');
router.post('/login', ctrlAuth.login);
```

controllers/authentication.js

```
module.exports.login = function(req, res) {

  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
    let token;

    // If Passport throws/catches an error
    if (err) {
      res.status(404).json(err);
      return;
    }

    // If a user is found
    if(user){
      token = user.generateJwt();
      res.status(200);
      res.json({
        "token" : token
      });
    } else {
      // If user is not found
      res.status(401).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res);

};
```

And finally, my config file

config/passport.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({
      email: username
    }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      //Return if user not found in database
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, {
          message: 'User not found'
        });
      }
      //Return if password is wrong
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, {
          message: 'Password is wrong'
        });
      }
      //If credentials are correct, return the user object
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

I believe I've narrowed the bug down to my validPassword function where I might be using bcrypt incorrectly.

```
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password){
  return bcrypt.compare(password, this.hash);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I narrowed my issue down to my validPassword method and found that I was using bcrypt incorrectly. Changed it to

```
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password){
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.hash);
};
```

Makes more sense after looking at the docs for bcrypt https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#readme